# Angular4 not work send post request to yii2 application

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, http, yii2

I use this code

```
this.http.post('http://l.example/angular/create/', {name: 'test'}).subscribe(
      (response) => console.log(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
```

to send post request to my Yii2 rest app but I get this error on the chrome console but when I use jquery `$.post` request work correctly

[image: Erorr list]

My Yii2 controller code

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class AngularController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Angular';

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;


        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();


        // add CORS filter
        $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
            'cors' => [
                'Origin' => ['*'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            ],

        ];
        $behaviors['contentNegotiator'] = [
            'class' => \yii\filters\ContentNegotiator::className(),
            'formats' => [
                'application/json' => \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
}
```

**Note**:

- Angular 4 `http.get` work correctly and list all records
- I Use Yii 2.0.14
- Angular 4.3.1

where is my mistake?

Comment: `http.post` takes a third parameter `options`. This includes the headers. You may have have to pass that in.

Comment: @ecain
I using this
`const header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json'});
const options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});`
but not work

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The same error as before

Comment: Trying taking out the accept. Or change the Content Type.

Comment: I changed them to xml but there was no change in the error

Comment: Maybe text/plain?

Comment: The same error as before :-(

Comment: Must be something else. I'm on mobile so I'll help tomorrow if no one else has.

Comment: @ecain do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predefined RESTful endpoints in Yii have no leading slash.

It should be:

```
'http://l.example/angular/create'
```

instead of

```
'http://l.example/angular/create/'
```